# Architecture for a MySQL MDBS

Tags: mysql, architecture

My coworker and I are tasked with redesigning our current Access databases in a MySQL environment. Between the two of us, this wont be a problem but we need to connect to other external databases that neither of us are sure how to do.

We have considered using views populated from the other databases, or have tables that copy the data on a timer but we feel that both of those will have negative performance implications.

I have looked but can not find anything that gives insight as to the best way to connect everything together.

One of the databases is managed by our phone system company, another is our in house data-warehouse. We also have the database managed by the workforce software company, and the final one will be ours that connects everything.

I'm hoping that someone here can point me in a direction as to how to connect everything together. Our DB will be on a server that we will have full access to if we need to write any additional software.

Comment: Define "external databases."  MySQL? Something else? How much administrative access do you have to the external databases and how far away are they (ping/round trip time)?